# How to use ABS in SUMIF in ARRAYFORUMULA

Tags: google-sheets, sum, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, sumifs

I have two Google Spreadsheets that I'm using to track budgets and transactions (I put them both on one sheet to simplify things for this question).

I'd like to use an ARRAYFORMULA function for my SPENT column that will sum all the transactions for a budget in a month, but I want to sum the absolute values of the transactions, not the recorded negative values.

Here is my Spreadsheet:
[image: Sample Budget and Transactions in Google Sheets]

[Link to Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jXZy5ykkOq-zodhIPilnvWA4oHoZoKzYcg2DoBRE9M8/edit?usp=sharing)

Here is a working formula for the SPENT column that sums the negative values:

```
={"Spent"; ArrayFormula(IF(LEN(A2:A), SUMIF(F2:F&G2:G, A2:A&J2, H2:H),))}
```

What I wish worked is this:

```
={"Spent"; ArrayFormula(IF(LEN(A2:A), SUMIF(F2:F&G2:G, A2:A&J2, ABS(H2:H)),))}
```

What do I have to do to sum absolute values in an ArrayFormula?

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: @player0 - I've added a link to the sheet. Let me know if you want edit rights.

Comment: your sheet is currently View Only.
Could you make the sheet editable so that I and others can better test and demonstrate solutions?

Comment: Yes, sorry. Should have done that from the beginning. You should be able to edit it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A="",,IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A, QUERY(F2:H, 
 "select F,sum(H) 
  where G = '"&J2&"'
  group by F 
  label sum(H)''"), 2, 0), 0)))
```

[image: 0]

then "`ABS`" could be:

[image: 0]

or your formula:

[image: 0]

or **`ABS`** before summing

[image: 0]

Comment: Thank you for looking into this, it's close, but I need a way to get the absolute value before summing. I tried modifying your Query function. I was thinking of doing something like "sum((H ^ 2) ^ 0.5)" instead of "sum(H)" but I found some documentation that says sum() requires a column ID and can't handle logic (https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#aggregation-functions).

Comment: if you want to have ABS before summing you can do: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6DsJE.png